# Foreach with Jquery find inputs

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input

I have this code like this:

```
<div class="phoneNumbers">
   <input />
</div>
<div class="phoneNumbers">
    <input />
</div>
<div class="phoneNumbers">
     <input />
</div>
```

What i want to do is find `input`s in the `div` from `phoneNumbers` and verify if they are empty or have white spaces.

I have this to find them but i don't know how to do a foreach to verify if they are empty or have white spaces.

```
$('.phoneNumbers').find('input')
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: Use HTML5 `required` and `pattern` attributes alongwith JS validations. `<input type="number" pattern="\d{10}" />`.

Comment: @Tushar why should the inputs be made compulsory with the `required` attribute ?

Comment: @Pogrindis That depends on the requirements. As it is not clear now, just added for info. if OP is interested in making all fields required. or maybe, first one `required` and others optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check all inputs and show invalid message for each input that is **empty** or **only has whitespaces**

```js
$('#a').click(function() {
  $('.error').remove();
  $('.phoneNumbers input').each(function(i, v) {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
      $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">invalid!</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phoneNumbers">
  <input />
</div>
<div class="phoneNumbers">
  <input />
</div>
<div class="phoneNumbers">
  <input />
</div>
<button id="a">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Maybe I am being nitpicky but the OP never said he wanted to invalidate empty inputs..

Comment: if i keep pressing the "validate" button it always adds another invalid and if i write some text it still remains invalid can i somehow remove it? If i can it's perfect

Comment: @user5852553 that's just a notification area for demonstration

Comment: Adjusted the validation messages

Comment: @TomB. Perfect :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.phoneNumbers').find('input').css("border", function(){
   return  this.value.trim() === "" ? "red" : "green";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` to reduce the result set.

Only use `.each` if you want to do something complicated on a single item at a time, if you're trying to find them then use `.filter`

```
$('.phoneNumbers')
  .find('input')
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == "";
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5jseuc77/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.phoneNumbers').find('input').each(function(index){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        // insert your code
        console.log("Empty input "+index);
    }
});
```

But the best way to require a value is to use "required" HTML attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check those inputs need something like this:

```
var pattern = /([^\s])/g,
    input   = $(this).find('input');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if($(input[i]).val().match(pattern)){
    /* DO SOMETHING */
  } else {
    /* EMPTY INPUT */
  }
}
```

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/o0g22484/1

PD: excuse my english...